# Regex alteration with shared sub expression with different prefix and suffix expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below regex which has 3 alternations (*see whole regex below*), each with its own prefix and suffix characters. I feel that this is repeating excessively and would like to simplify if possible. I am matching values in an improperly formed JSON string to replace values that do not have a key with indexed keys.

Each alternation should match a prefix and suffix pair with the sub expression. I have 3 pairs at this time, but that might change. If I had several more pairs the whole regex would become a nightmare to modify and understand if I had a need to modify the repeated sub expression.

**Question**

How might I shorten the the *whole regex* below without needing to repeat the *sub expression* for the listed pairs of suffixes and prefixes?

**Sub expression, repeated in each alternation**

```
("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")
```

**prefix/suffix pairs**

1. { ,
2. , ,
3. , }

**Whole Regex**

```
/\{("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=\})/g
```

**Test Strings**

- `{"trailer":"","pallet":"A","date":"11-Dec-15","c","z","a"}`
- `{"trailer":"","pallet":"A","a","date":"11-Dec-15"}`
- `{"a","trailer":"","pallet":"A","date":"11-Dec-15"}`
- `{"a","trailer":"","pallet":"A","date":"11-Dec-15","z\""}`
- `{"trailer":"","pallet":"A","11-Dec-15"}`
- `{"trailer\"","pallet":"A","11-Dec\"-15","z\""}`

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/rS4wZ9/2)

Please limit answers to regex alternations and not JSON validation techniques as I am trying to gain a better understanding of regex and this is just the example that I using.

Comment: You can use dynamic regex building with `RegExp` constructor: declare the `("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")` as a building block variable, and then just reuse it in the pattern. You will have to double all backslashes though.

Comment: If I did'nt understood wrong, you can use single expression to (multiple) matching all parts at once by simply using lookbefore and lookahead assets. Each one using multiple alternatives to match either of valid delimitation characters in each case.

Comment: @bitifet I had tried this before but have discovered that you cannot use expressions within a lookbehind so I would have to hard code each occurance. That still leaves me having to specify each character that I wish. So either I have to generate my regex using javascript strings or use the RegExp function which does appear to do just that.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I understand and agree with the general idea, how so ever if a user is browsing the javascript tag, this question will not make as much sense.

Comment: With JavaScript, that's the best you can do.  Of all the Perl-derived flavors, it's the most limited.  Are you interested in answers targeting other flavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the regular expression can be simplified from:

```
/\{("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=\})/g
```

To:

```
/{("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=})/g
```

Removing the escaping of the `{` and `}` as it's not required for JavaScript's regex engine.

This it is not possible to remove your explicit repeated pattern `("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")` in JavaScript.

JavaScript doesn't not support all the same regular expression functionality PCRE based (PHP, C++, Perl, etc.) regex engine supports.

For example in PHP / C++ you could do this:

```
{("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,((?1))(?=,)|,((?1))(?=})
```

For Perl 5.22 you would need to escape that `{` again so it would look something like this:

```
m/\{("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")(?=,)|,((?1))(?=,)|,((?1))(?=})/g
```

This `(?1)` is a subroutine call to match the regex inside capturing group `1` which in this case is `("(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*")`.